# image processing in python- hue, saturation, contrast and brightness

Tags: python, image-processing

i was wondering if there is a way to extract statistic or values like: brightness, contrast, hue, saturation and sharpness from an image in python?

Comment: you can always convert the image from RGB to [HSV or HSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) domain. And to do that you could use [opencv with python](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). But what exactly do you mean by *"extract statistic or values "*? You want a single value for the whole image?

Comment: Are you looking for mean values of brightness, hue and saturation averaged over the entire image? What units are you expecting for sharpness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no automatic way to do this.

OpenCV can be used for some estimations, like this: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/07/blur-detection-with-opencv/

You can also analyse image histogram (use numpy to make it) to detect images with very high or low brightness.